# Разные масштабы для оси графика PyQtGraph в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqtgraph, plotwidget

У меня есть интерфейс на PyQt5, в котором по нажатию кнопки Старт строится график, который я сделал с помощью PyQtGraph. На графике строятся три линии. У зеленой и синей диапазон значений по оси Y от 0 до 200, а у красной от 0 до 0,5. Как я могу сделать разные масштабы для разных линий, а так же обозначить на оси Y две шкалы значений - от 0 до 200 и от 0 до 0,5?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
import pyqtgraph
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QThread, QTimer, QObject, pyqtSignal, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout, QMainWindow,  QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QApplication
import sys
import random


def get_kl_test():
    choices = [50, 50, 50, 51, 51, 51, 52, 52, 52]
    list = [random.choice(choices) for i in range(11)]
    return list


def get_iopd_test():
    choices = [0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3]
    return random.choice(choices)


class Graph(PlotWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setBackground('white')
        self.addLegend()
        self.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        self.setYRange(0, 255, padding=0)


class ReadingWorker(QObject):
    update_graph = pyqtSignal(list, list, list, list)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.time_from_start = 0
        self.time_values = []
        self.green_values = []
        self.blue_values = []
        self.red_values = []

    def run(self):
        self.read()
        self.update_time()

    def read(self):
        ipd_values = get_kl_test()
        iopd_value = get_iopd_test()

        self.green_values.append(ipd_values[0])
        self.blue_values.append(ipd_values[1])
        self.red_values.append(iopd_value)
        self.time_values.append(self.time_from_start)

        self.update_graph.emit(
            self.green_values, self.blue_values, self.red_values, self.time_values)
        QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.read)

    def update_time(self):
        self.time_from_start += 1
        QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.update_time)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1300, 700)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.layout_main_window = QVBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.layout_main_window)

        # конфигурация тулбара
        self.layout_toolbar = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout_toolbar.addStretch(1)
        self.btn_start = QPushButton("Старт")
        self.btn_start.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.layout_toolbar.addWidget(self.btn_start)
        self.layout_main_window.addLayout(self.layout_toolbar)

        # конфигурация графика
        self.graph = Graph()
        self.layout_main_window.addWidget(self.graph)

    def start(self):
        self.reading_thread = QThread(parent=self)
        self.reading_widget = ReadingWorker()
        self.reading_widget.moveToThread(self.reading_thread)
        self.reading_widget.update_graph.connect(self.draw_graph)
        self.reading_thread.started.connect(self.reading_widget.run)
        self.reading_thread.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(list, list, list, list)
    def draw_graph(self, ipd_1_values, ipd_2_values, iopd_values, time_values):
        
        self.graph.plotItem.clearPlots()
        pen_ipd_1 = pyqtgraph.mkPen(color='green', width=4)
        pen_ipd_2 = pyqtgraph.mkPen(color='blue', width=4, style=Qt.DashDotLine)
        pen_iopd = pyqtgraph.mkPen(color='red', width=4, style=Qt.DashLine)

        line_ipd_1 = self.graph.plotItem.addItem(pyqtgraph.PlotCurveItem(
            time_values, 
            ipd_1_values,
            pen=pen_ipd_1,
            name='1'
        ))
        line_ipd_2 = self.graph.plotItem.addItem(pyqtgraph.PlotCurveItem(
            time_values, 
            ipd_2_values,
            pen=pen_ipd_2,
            name='2'
        ))
        line_iopd = self.graph.plotItem.addItem(pyqtgraph.PlotCurveItem(
            time_values, 
            iopd_values,
            pen=pen_iopd,
            name='3'
        ))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```